# saving workflows events

Tags: workflow

I've been reading about workflows from this [site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). I noted that he workflows events last 60 days after the workflow is completed. Is it possible to save these events longer? I was thinking in taking the data directly from the database, but I don't know where to find the correct table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have farm administrator rights you can look at Disabling the workflow cleanup.

[Link to article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522(v=office.14).aspx)